# php laravel database migration

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.5. and I am trying to migrate of all my database migration files.but I am getting an error while trying to migrate:

In *Macroable.php* line 74:

> Method increment does not exist.

**this is my macroable.php file**

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Support\Traits;

use Closure;
use BadMethodCallException;

trait Macroable
{
    /**
     * The registered string macros.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $macros = [];

    /**
     * Register a custom macro.
     *
     * @param  string    $name
     * @param  callable  $macro
     * @return void
     */
    public static function macro($name, callable $macro)
    {
        static::$macros[$name] = $macro;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if macro is registered.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function hasMacro($name)
    {
        return isset(static::$macros[$name]);
    }

    /**
     * Dynamically handle calls to the class.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     */
    public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException("Method {$method} does not exist.");
        }

        if (static::$macros[$method] instanceof Closure) {
            return call_user_func_array(Closure::bind(static::$macros[$method], null, static::class), $parameters);
        }

        return call_user_func_array(static::$macros[$method], $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Dynamically handle calls to the class.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     */
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException("Method {$method} does not exist.");
        }

        if (static::$macros[$method] instanceof Closure) {
            return call_user_func_array(static::$macros[$method]->bindTo($this, static::class), $parameters);
        }

        return call_user_func_array(static::$macros[$method], $parameters);
    }
}
```

**this is my user database migration file**

```
public function up()
{
    if (!Schema::hasTable('users')) {   // if this table does not exist then execite 
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {  //table method is used to update table fields ect
        $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('middle_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();

        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();

    });
}
```

and I have some other migrations files as well.. can anybody help me out to get rid of this error....

Comment: `Method increment does not exist` suggests that you're using `->increment()` instead of `->increments()` (with an **s**), but your code has the correct `->increments()`. Is this your only migration file?

Comment: no i have some other files as well..

Comment: i have sorted sorted increments method error..u saved my a lot time..thanks for your support..